# Can't setViewControllers in my UITabBarController

Tags: xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I can't get setViewControllers to set the view controllers for my `UITabBarController`.

In the implementation for my `UITabBarController` subclass, I have:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationItem.title = @"Test";
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.title = @"To Test";

    NSMutableArray *aViewControllersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:2];
    UINavigationController* aNavigationController;

    aNavigationController = [UIViewControllerOne alloc];
    [aViewControllersArray addObject:aNavigationController];
    [aNavigationController release];

    aNavigationController = [UIViewControllerTwo alloc];
    [aViewControllersArray addObject:aNavigationController];
    [aNavigationController release];

    [self setViewControllers:aViewControllersArray animated:TRUE];
    [aViewControllersArray release];       
}
```

The aViewControllersArray has the two `UIViewControllers`, but the viewControllers property of the `UITabBarController` is nil.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

In creating my UITabBarController I had been doing

```
[MyUITabBarController alloc]
```

rather than

```
[[MyUITabBarController alloc] init]
```

Adding `init` saved the day.